# Get all the questions from database at a time or one ques at a time?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring, jsp

I am working on Java Quiz web application using spring, hibernate, jsp and mysql. I am in confusion whether:

- to get all the questions stored in the database at a time and send it as json to the jsp file where the questions are iterated using Javascript?

OR

- get one question at a time using AJAX?

Comment: There are so many variables to a question like this, it is really hard to have any one right answer on a forum like this. I think you will get a lot of answers on both sides. In general, you will get better answers here when more of the work has been done up-front and some specific issue has been identified.

Answer (score 1):

There is a concept of paginating result sets that are too large to fit on one page. most frameworks, including jsp would have JSP tags for rendering large tables.

Making a separate AJAX call for each user would probably be too much since you would incur network round trip.

Another approach could be client side (or even server side) caching.

If you are using HTML5 look at local storage. If server side is your preference look at memcached.